# Atiyah-Macdonald Q1.27 Ring of Polynomial Equations on X.

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I do not understand his last statement where he mentions that $P(X)$ is the ring of polynomial functions on $X$. What does he mean by that? Is it the ring of polynomials  with coefficients in $X$? If so how is $X$ a ring in the first place.

Comment: The explanation after that statement might help. Think of it as 'restricting' polynomials to $X$ itself. Yet another way to think of it is as the set of (equivalence classes of) polynomials in $k[t_1, \dots, t_n]$ which agree on $X$ (but may not agree in points not in $X$).

Comment: No: whose arguments are in $X$, i.e. such that the domain of those polynomial functions is $X$.

Comment: Since it hasn't been mentioned yet: This usually called the coordinate ring of the affine variety $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion with the indeterminate $X$ commonly used in polynomials let me write $V$ instead of $X$.

With $V$ being a subset of $K^n$ we can consider polynomial functions $p:V\rightarrow K$, meaning functions which are given by evaluating a polynomial $p‘\in K[T_1,...,T_n]$ at points in $V$. Now two polynomials $p‘,p‘‘$ yield the same polynomial function on $V$, if they agree at each point, that is if $p‘-p‘‘=0$ on $X$. But this is exactly the defining property of $I(V)$, so the set of polynomial functions on $X$ is precisely the set $K[T_1,...,T_n]/I(V) =: K[V]$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also what he means by P(X) is generated as a K-algebra by the coordinate functions. I know that a k-algebra is a vector space over k with a bilinear map.   So P(X) is a k-algebra. But what does it mean to be generated by the coordinate functions.

Answer (score 0):

I will mostly echo what has been said already, but hopefully rephrase it in a useful manner.

The most important takeaway is that polynomials are not the same as polynomial functions. A polynomial $f \in k[t_1, \ldots, t_n]$ is just some formal expression, whereas a polynomial function is a function $k^n \to k$ given by $(k_1, \ldots, k_n) \mapsto f(k_1, \ldots, k_n)$. That is, you substitute some particular values from $k$ in place of the formal variables $t_1, \ldots, t_n$.

We often conflate the two, because if we deal with $k=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ or any field of characteristic $0$, the polynomials and polynomial functions coincide. However, this is not true in general and different polynomials can give the same polynomial functions in a general setting.

The precise condition when this happens is: $f$ and $g$ give the same polynomial function if $f-g \in I(X)$. So you can think of the ring of polynomial functions as the quotient $\frac{k[x_1, \ldots, k_n]}{I(X)}$.

---

To answer your question explicitly, the role of $X$ is just to tell which ideal you have to quotient by. The polynomial functions still have coefficients in $k$.